# trying to render same react component with dynamic props (the props come from a json file)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

here is my sample nested json - the lowest level json contains the entries for the props (e.g. articleClassName is the prop and image featured is the propvalue that needs to be passed.)

```
{
  "TopTrends": {
    "Game1": {
      "articleClassName": "image featured",
      "imgSource": "../../../static/images/crsed (1)306.jpg",
      "articleHeader": "Cuisine Royale - Desktop Game",
      "articleDescr": "Most Popular games in US. 1+ millions players are playing now. Join your rivelaries.",
      "buttonClassName": "search-container",
      "articleUrl": "'google.com'",
      "articleLabel": "Play Now"
    },
    "Game2": {
      "articleClassName": "image featured",
      "imgSource": "../../../static/images/crsed (1)307.jpg",
      "articleHeader": "Cuisine Royale - Desktop Game",
      "articleDescr": "Most Popular games in US. 1+ millions players are playing now. Join your rivelaries.",
      "buttonClassName": "search-container",
      "articleUrl": "'google.com'",
      "articleLabel": "Play Now"
    }
  },
  "Travel": {
    "Travel1": {
      "articleClassName": "image featured",
      "imgSource": "../../../static/images/crsed (1)300.jpg",
      "articleHeader": "Cuisine Royale - Desktop Game",
      "articleDescr": "Most Popular games in US. 1+ millions players are playing now. Join your rivelaries.",
      "buttonClassName": "search-container",
      "articleUrl": "'google.com",
      "articleLabel": "Play Now"
    },
    "Travel2": {
      "articleClassName": "image featured",
      "imgSource": "../../../static/images/crsed (1)300.jpg",
      "articleHeader": "Cuisine Royale - Desktop Game",
      "articleDescr": "Most Popular games in US. 1+ millions players are playing now. Join your rivelaries.",
      "buttonClassName": "search-container",
      "articleUrl": "'google.com'",
      "articleLabel": "Play Now"
    }
  },

  "Household": {
    "Household1": {
      "articleClassName": "image featured",
      "imgSource": "../../../static/images/crsed (1)300.jpg",
      "articleHeader": "Cuisine Royale - Desktop Game",
      "articleDescr": "Most Popular games in US. 1+ millions players are playing now. Join your rivelaries.",
      "buttonClassName": "search-container",
      "articleUrl": "'google.com'",
      "articleLabel": "Play Now"
    },
    "Household2": {
      "articleClassName": "image featured",
      "imgSource": "../../../static/images/crsed (1)300.jpg",
      "articleHeader": "Cuisine Royale - Desktop Game",
      "articleDescr": "Most Popular games in US. 1+ millions players are playing now. Join your rivelaries.",
      "buttonClassName": "search-container",
      "articleUrl": "'google.com'",
      "articleLabel": "Play Now"
    }
  }
}
```

I have a component where these props need to be passed -

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function Article(props) {
    return (    
            <article>
                        <a href="#" className={props.articleClassName}><img src={props.imgSource} alt="" /></a>
                        <header>
                            <h3><a href="#">{props.articleHeader}</a></h3>
                        </header>
                        <p>{props.articleDescr} </p>
                        <button className={props.buttonClassName} onclick={props.articleUrl} type="text"> {props.articleLabel} </button>
            </article>
    )
}
```

and the main component where the above component needs to be embedded dynamically based on the number of rows returned from the json file -

```
export default function Carousel() {              

    const [data , setData]=useState([]);
    const getData=()=>{
      fetch('./CarouselData.json'
      ,{
        headers : { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
         }
      }
      )
        .then(function(response){
          console.log('this is the response ' + response)
        //   console.log(response)
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(myJson) {
        //   console.log(myJson);
         setData(myJson)
        });
    }      

    useEffect(()=>{
      getData()
    },[]);
   

   return (
    <div style={{ top: 0 }}>
       <section className="carousel">
            <div className="reel">
                <article> 
                    <Article articleClassName="image featured" imgSource="../../../static/images/crsed (1)300.jpg"
                    articleHeader="Cuisine Royale - Desktop Game" 
                    articleDescr="Most Popular games in US. 1+ millions players are playing now. Join your rivelaries."
                    buttonClassName="search-container"
                    articleUrl="'https://google.com'"
                    articleLabel="Play Now"
                    />

                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}
```

As you can see, in the above component, the  component is being rendered after passing the props into it. I want to loop through the json data (data) and pass the props dynamically while rendering this  component.

I have tried converting the data variable into an array - but being new to javascript and react - always getting syntax errors. Any help would be appreciated. Please ignore if there are syntax errors in the posted code - I have deleted and copied a lot of stuff to paste it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first convert your data into an array:

```
var articles = [];
for (const topHeader in data) {
    for (const title in data[topHeader]) {
      data[topHeader][title].header = topHeader;
      data[topHeader][title].title = title;
      articles.push(data[topHeader][title]);
    }
}
```

After that in react you can use the .map on the array to create all the components

```
return <div>
    {
        articles.map(x => {
            return (
                <Article key={x.header + ' - ' + x.title}
                    articleClassName={x.articleClassName}
                    articleHeader={x.articleHeader} />)
        });
    }
</div>;
```

If you want to create 3 arrays for the 3 tops header if they are constant, etc... you can play around with it.

The key section is to ensure react, when it re-render the section, it to prevent it from deleting the html content of the DOM and re-creating none stop, but to link that object element to that DOM object. You want the key to uniquely identify the object and to not have duplicated key.

Comment: Thanks a ton - works like a charm! I had no idea arrays in javascript can be accessed with a json type reference and vice versa! I would like to understand more about your last comment though (regarding the probable deletion of the html content of the DOM by react?) Thanks again!

Comment: @VikasBhartiya In your JSON, if you use [] instead of {} it would create a javascript array. Thus you could change your format for your JSON input and you wouldn't need any manipulation. You can read this article regarding keys inside react https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys